# Mac keyboard shortcuts

Tags: shortcut

Just for my curiosity and knowledge, I just learned that CMD + M will minimize and bring to the dock the active application.  But what is the **opposite shortcuts** in order to bring back the application to the screen from the dock?

Thank you so much and have a wonderful day.

Comment: A similar alternative is to hide the window rather than minimize it. I believe the shortcut for that is command h

Comment: Try a google search on "os x unminimize shortcut"

Answer (score 1):

No need to try all key combos until it works, because you'll be disappointed. Check out [this page from Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236), and you'll find, sadly, there is no reverse key combo because Finder has nothing to work with - no focus for the command.

Once the window is closed, not even Command - Tab > [minimized app icon] will open the app window!

The only way to open the app is to click on its icon in the Dock.

Answer (score 0):

As Tom Gewecke said, I google "os x unminimized shortcut" and I found the answer.

Check out this link: https://superuser.com/questions/196141/keyboard-shortcut-to-unhide-or-unminimize-a-window-in-os-x